# Good approach to webRTC connection for your server

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc

So I have an application that uses webRTC to set up a video chat between 2 browsers. I'm using node.js for the application and socket.io to make the handshake. I have made a successful test in the chrome browser in connecting the clients so now the next step is to allow this to be used by more people.

I was wondering what would be the best way to approach the server side of creating 'rooms' and connecting two people who would like to chat. In the test I just put the one who created the offer in an object and if the second person matched the first (by UUID or a keyword) then the connection would be made but what would be a better, more secure, and more fitting method to do this with more people?

My application currently has MySQL so should I make use of a table? I feel like that would be time consuming/too much calling to a db... Should I focus more on Socket.io? Can node's socket.io handle a lot of connections to the server well enough?

If my question isn't clear please tell me.

P.S. any GOOD tutorials or articles on setting up a webRTC connection on mozilla would be great. I can add the connection but for some reason adding the stream of the one who 'creates offer' isn't being sent over.

Answer (score 0):

A "room" in WebRTC will just be use for signaling, a way of sending messages before the actual connection is initiated.

"My application currently has MySQL so should I make use of a table?" - that's not exactly the best approach. If your application uses a framework/technology/etc, it doesn't mean that you should use it everywhere. You should use a technology when it answers best your needs. If such a room has to have some persistent attributes, then it makes sense to make use of a persistent storage, such as a database.

Comment: I see what you mean when you say "If your application uses a framework/technology/etc, it doesn't mean that you should use it everywhere", that is very true. My intention was to keep a record of such sessions so considered the option. So do you think this would be something that socket.io could handle? Helping to directly connect two users who are on the site simultaneously despite all the other users?

Comment: That's exactly what signaling is for. And yes,  something like socket.io can do the job. You just need a way to identify such a session/room,  usually an unique code.